# Linear algebra system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the following linear system:

$x - y  +  2z + 3w = 12$

$ x - 2y +   z +  w  = 8$

$4x +  y +  2z -  w  = 3$

1) find all solutions of the system. Write the solution in Vector Form
2) find all solutions of the corresponding homogeneous system

I have turned this into a matrix and worked it out two ways resulting in different outcomes, neither of which is solvable...

I'll try to show my work, but I am new to this site and the formatting for matrices is fairly hard to figure out...

1 -1 2 3 12
1 -2 1 1 8
4 1 2 -1 3 (-4 row1)

1 -1  2   3  12
1 -2  1   1   8 (-row1)
0  5 -6 -13 -45

1 -1  2   3  12
0 -1 -1  -2  -4
0  5 -6 -13 -45(+5row2)

1 -1   2   3  12
0 -1  -1  -2  -4
0  0 -11 -23 -65

from here I don't think there's anything else I can do, I'm fairly sure there are infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Let's see the work done so we can help.

Comment: Wow thanks, but of course.

Comment: By [this computation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Row+Reduce+{{1%2C-1%2C2%2C3%2C12}%2C{1%2C-2%2C1%2C1%2C8}%2C{4%2C1%2C2%2C-1%2C3}}), it appears that there should be a non-empty solution set.  If you show us what you did, we could try to figure out where you went wrong.

Comment: I edited the question with my work, any thoughts? I'm thinking that It just needs to be put in vector form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh of course there is more that can be done!

So starting from where you left, I would first multiple $R_2$ with the scalar $(-1)$ and then add the new $R_2$ to $R_1$ and replace it. Then I get,

$$
        \left({\begin{matrix}
        1 & 0 & 3 & 5 & 16 \\
        0 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 4 \\
        0 & 0 & -11 & -23 & -65 \\
        \end{matrix}}\right) 
$$

$$\underrightarrow{\left({\frac{-1}{11}}\right) R_3 \ \text{and} -1 R_3 + R_2 \ \text{and} -3R_3 + R_1 } $$

$$ \left({\begin{matrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{-14}{11} & \frac{-19}{11}\\
        0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{-1}{11} & \frac{-21}{11} \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{23}{11} & \frac{65}{11} \\
        \end{matrix}}\right)   $$

Now translating back to equations you have,

$$ x =  \frac{14}{11}w + \frac{19}{11}$$
$$ y = \frac{1}{11}w + \frac{21}{11}$$
$$ z = \frac{-23}{11}w + \frac{-65}{11}$$

Now any value you take for $w$ will solve the system. The method underlined here is made formal in [Linear Algebra by Hoffman, Kunze](https://www.google.lk/search?q=Linear%20Algebra%20hoffman%20kunze&oq=Linear%20Algebra%20hoffman%20kunze&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.6506j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) which you should definitely read.

Now the solution set in vector form would be,

$$  \left({\begin{matrix}
        x  \\
        y  \\
        z  \\
        w  \\
\end{matrix}}\right)  = w\left({\begin{matrix}
        \frac{14}{11}  \\
        \frac{1}{11}  \\
        \frac{-23}{11}  \\
        1  \\
\end{matrix}}\right) + \left({\begin{matrix}
        \frac{19}{11}  \\
        \frac{21}{11}  \\
        \frac{-65}{11}  \\
        0  \\
\end{matrix}}\right)$$

where $w$ is any scalar in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Could you explain why when converting it back into the equations the sign of the last two rows change? Shouldn't the last column keep it's sign? for example: z = -23/11w + 65/11

Comment: Actually your partly right. The equation should be $ z = \frac{-23}{11}w - \frac{65}{11} $ since the last row in the matrix $ 0 \; 0 \; 1 \; \frac{23}{11} \; \frac{-65}{11}  $ represents the equation $z + \frac{23}{11}w =  \frac{-65}{11} $. So lslight alteration needed.